# What is the non-homebrew goblin with the highest CR?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, goblin

One player in my group has a character who absolutely hates goblins. He tracks them, and only want to find information about them.

We want to know what is the strongest, most difficult to beat goblin we can find, that is not homebrew.

Comment: When you say goblin, do you mean the creatures specifically known as goblins, or any goblinoid (e.g. goblins, orcs, bugbears, and hobgoblins)?

Comment: The accepted answer covers both, so I guess the OP cared about both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [hobgoblin warlord](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hobgoblin-warlord) is the highest CR goblinoid (CR 6).

You can find it in the *Monster Manual* on page 187.

If you're looking for just a goblin, the [goblin boss](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/goblin-boss) and [nilbog](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/nilbog) (*Volo's*, p. 182) represent the highest CR of 1.

I was able to find this quickly by utilizing D&D Beyond's search for Monsters and using the subtype for goblinoid and then sorting by CR.

Comment: I would note that for questions of this kind, [filtering dndbeyond's monster lists by tag](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-tags=64&sort=-cr) is a very convenient tool.